Need to enable Email button within task object
I am trying to enable Email action button within the tasks object similar to this.

However, I'm unable to add either the Activity timeline that contains the email button within the task object or just add the email button within the task object.
I've tried adding the Email lightning component to the task Page Layouts and have ensured that the Deliverability of emails is set to "All System email"
Please suggest if this is possible and how can this be accomplished.
P.S : The business use case is that they would like to send a clarifying email when assigned a task and the business users feel that that having an email action within the tasks object view would be more productive.

Does the Task object have record types? If yes try assigning the record type for the required user profiles and check again .
Are you enabling the advanced activity timeline for all users or only selected few.
For Individual users - got to User profile -> Settings -> Record Page settings and set activity Time line .
For All users -> Quick Find -> Record Page Settings -> Default Activities View (desktop only) -> Select advanced activity timeline.

I am trying to enable it for All users and the default setting for All users has the advanced activity timeline already selected. However, this still doesn't seem to work.

do you  have record types on the Task object?

yes, it does have record types

Looks like a duplicate of Sent emails not visible under Task object in salesforce Lightning

You would need to enable activities in the object settings. I would belive it being custom object.

That being said for the email quick action there should be an email field on object or lookup to contact/lead

The task object that we are using a standard object and not a custom object. So, I don't see the optional features to enable "allow activities"
